# awk print from passwd but only with userid > 1000

Tags: awk, scripting, gawk, passwd

Ok I've done:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print $1 }'
```

- -F ==> Specify a file seperator for delineating data fields in a line
- $1 ==> Represents the first field in the input

but how to only print users with `id` over `1000`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As steeldriver pointed out in a comment, you could simply add a condition to the print statement so that it only prints when the condition is true:

```
awk -F: '$3 > 1000 { print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

Here, the `$3 > 1000` is the condition. Awk can also read files directly, so you can avoid a `cat` and a pipe `|` by providing the filename directly to awk, either directly as above, or with a redirection:

```
awk -F: '$3 > 1000 { print $1 }' < /etc/passwd
```